# Generators on exterior algebra in Flanders' Differential Forms text

Tags: differential-forms

What does Harley Flanders mean when he states that f is defined on the generators of $\Lambda ^p \textbf(L)$? What are the generators?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nPEZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: $f$ is a linear map (more precisely an alternating multilinear map) acting on the vector space $\Lambda^p$, so that it is completely described by its effect on the basis vectors (the so-called *generators* in the present case), as you already know it from linear algebra.

Comment: I also believe that he means basis by generators. I hesitated to make this conclusion only because he didn't explicitly state it even though he mentions bases earlier in the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

No, he doesn't mean a basis. The generators of $\Lambda^p L$ are the so-called primitive $p$-vectors, i.e., the wedge products of any $p$ vectors (which are interesting only when these $p$ vectors are linearly independent). Any $p$-vector is a linear combination of these, but they need not be linearly independent.